# Update a Mysql table based on a value from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called questions with columns `(id, title, message, permalink)`. I want to update the `permalink` column based on the value `title` and also replace the empty space in the title with an underscore.

This is my query:

```
UPDATE questions AS q SET permalink = SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(LOWER(b.title),' ','_'), '_', 4) FROM questions AS b;
```

But I got the below error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM questions AS b' at line 1
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GMB Question updated.

Comment: UPDATE within the record do not use FROM clause. In any DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query operates on a single row. You don’t need aliases or additional select, just:

```
UPDATE questions
SET permalink = SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(LOWER(title),' ','_'), '_', 4):
```